# Python and CX_Oracle Invalid SQL Statement

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm writing a Python script to fetch some values from Oracle, but by the middle I have to set an ID to a package so it can create the corresponding view with the data I want.

I'm trying to execute:

```
ora_query = cursor.execute("EXECUTE VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG.SET_COMPANY_ID(P_COMPANY_ID => '1111111111')")
```

and it returns me:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

In SQL Developer I can use this execute statement and it gives me the outcome. Am I using the cursor.execute wrong?

This is the package:

```
create or replace package VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG as
  procedure SET_COMPANY_ID(P_COMPANY_ID VARCHAR2);

  function GET_COMPANY_ID
    return VARCHAR2;
    
end VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG;
```

And this is the package body:

```
create or replace package body VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG as
  G_COMPANY_ID   VARCHAR2(255);


  procedure SET_COMPANY_ID(P_COMPANY_ID VARCHAR2) as
  begin
    G_COMPANY_ID := P_COMPANY_ID;
  end;

  function GET_COMPANY_ID
    return VARCHAR2 is
  begin
    return G_COMPANY_ID;
  end;

  
end VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [`EXEC[UTE] statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6) is an SQL Plus command, not a SQL statement. SQL Developer processes SQL Plus commands as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you provided is not a valid SQL statement. It is a SQL*Plus command. You want to do something like this instead:

```
company_id = '1111111111'
cursor.callproc('VW_WEEKLY_CALL_LOG_PKG.SET_COMPANY_ID', [company_id])
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! I wasn't aware that the packages used the "callproc" too.
I now know what I was doing wrong. I wasn't fetching anything from the cursor after setting the company_id and doing a select statement to get the info from the DB. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!